# I can't run the executable of a game made with Bevy

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, bevy

I was following a bevy tutorial and I thought:

> *What if I run the executable? After all, I will want to share my games in the future.*

When i ran the executable, it said that cannot find 2 dlls, **bevy_dylib-5d51f44a630848aa.dll** and **std-1cd530251ef8500f.dll**.
It is interesting because has a file  called `bevy_dylib.dll` in the folder and should searching this.

But I found `bevy_dylib-5d51f44a630848aa.dll` inside the `deps`, while `std-1cd530251ef8500f.dll` seems just don't exist.

Same thing happens with this code:

```
use bevy::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    App::new().add_system(hello).run();
}

fn hello() {
    println!("Hello");
}
```

but it doesn't happend when I use `cargo run`.
Other times I've noticed that apparently has some difference between using cargo run and running the executable.

#### Anyone know how **compile correctly** a game made with bevy? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you copy the binary from? Did you copy the debug one or the `cargo build --release` binary?

Comment: What are the dependencies in your `Cargo.toml` file? It's possible one of them has its own deps, that require doing a `sudo apt-get install libXXX-dev`, for instance. Cargo can only install the rust-code of a package, not do an install of apt-packages. (Assuming that's the problem, you will have to check each individual dependency for install-instructions).

Comment: I added 3 lines, 2 for compile the packages in `opt-level=3` and `bevy = { version = "0.7.0", features = ["dynamic"] }`

Comment: Why did you add the `"dynamic"` feature?

Comment: @JohnC Not sure how helpful your response is, given his libraries are `.dll`s and his OS therefore is most likely Windows

Comment: `std-1cd530251ef8500f.dll` is very suspicious - are you running it from within a `git-bash`? If yes, try running it from a `cmd` or `powershell` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is a big difference between *development* and *release*. Your *development* configuration should be focused on low build times, and your *release* configuration should be focused on portability.

`Bevy` recommends using the `"dynamic"` feature for low build times. If you want to compile for release, though, you should remove that flag. This is most likely where most of your problems come from.

Another problem that arises is that by default, Rust on Windows depends on the MSVC Runtime. You might want to enable static runtime linking to compile the runtime into the executable. This increases its size a little, but that should be fine.

The best way to enable static runtime linking on windows is to create the file `.cargo/config.toml` in your project directory, and then paste into it:

```ini
[target.x86_64-pc-windows-msvc]
rustflags = ["-Ctarget-feature=+crt-static"]
```

So to sum up:

- Remove the `"dynamic"` flag from `bevy`
- Build with the `crt-static` flag

Then, you should be able to copy-paste your binary to arbitrary windows systems.

Note, however, that further dependencies of your project could introduce new runtime dependencies. You might have to deliver the respective `.dll` files with your executable, then; this is common practice for games.

---

### Further remarks

You can check for runtime dependencies with the `ldd` tool in `git-bash`.
Using it on my executable without `+crt-static` shows:

```
> ldd target/release/<my cratename>.exe
        ntdll.dll => /c/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7ffc8c410000)
        KERNEL32.DLL => /c/WINDOWS/System32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x7ffc8afc0000)
        KERNELBASE.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7ffc89d80000)
        bcrypt.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/bcrypt.dll (0x7ffc89d00000)
        ucrtbase.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/ucrtbase.dll (0x7ffc8a370000)
        VCRUNTIME140.dll => /c/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/VCRUNTIME140.dll (0x7ffc6cba0000)
```

After linking with `+crt-static`, it shows:

```
> ldd target/release/<my cratename>.exe
        ntdll.dll => /c/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7ffc8c410000)
        KERNEL32.DLL => /c/WINDOWS/System32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x7ffc8afc0000)
        KERNELBASE.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7ffc89d80000)
        bcrypt.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/bcrypt.dll (0x7ffc89d00000)
```

Comment: when this problem arose, i thought `"dynamic"` feature the could be the problem. But i probably removed from cargo and what I ran was `cargo build -r --features bevy/dynamic` and forgotten to try only  `cargo build -r`