# Rust - How to remove the dependency on ucrtbase.dll?

Tags: windows, rust, dll

When compiling my Rust app in Windows 10, it is linked against `ucrtbase.dll`; however, this dll does not exist on some editions of Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter, making my app impossible to execute.

I tried setting `-Ctarget-feature=+crt-static` as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73098098/4851350), but it did not do anything; `ldd app.exe` still shows this dll.

Is there a way of removing the dependency on this dll?

Answer (score 0):

If your Rust app does not depend on C libraries that specifically require the MSVC toolchain, you can build it for the `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` (or `i686-pc-windows-gnu`, to build for 32-bit CPUs) target instead. [This target links to DLLs that are available in all Windows versions](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/2355).

For more information about the different Windows ABIs, you can check out [this documentation page](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/installation/windows.html).

Comment: Sadly, even building against x86_64-pc-windows-gnu still links against ucrtbase.dll :(

Comment: That's sad to hear. Have you checked out [`static_vcruntime`](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/static-vcruntime-distribute-windows-msvc-binaries-without-needing-to-deploy-vcruntime-dll/57599)? It doesn't address the problem of getting rid of `ucrtbase.dll`, but its techniques maybe help you find a solution to your problem.